# Using DT package with knitrBootstrap

Tags: r, knitr, knitrbootstrap

Does anyone know if there are issues using the [DT](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/) package in conjunction with [knitrBootstap](https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap)?  When I try to render a data table using the `datatable` function, the table itself does not render when the document is knit.

I've tried using the simple example below in both a standard markdown document as well as the knitrBootstrap styled document.  It prints in the standard HTML output, but not in the bootstrap styled document:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this or how to workaround this?  I've tried altering a few chunk options including `results='asis`, but it didn't seem to help.

I am able to workaround this by using kable, setting an id and then utilizing javascript outside of the markdown chunk to render the table

```
kable(value_test, "html", table.attr = "id=\"test_table\"")
```

followed by:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test_table').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the current status of this, but a few years ago Leonardo Collado-Torres had worked out the proper way to do this with rCharts.

https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap/issues/21

Most likely the issue is that the jQuery libraries are being loaded twice, once by knitrBootstrap and again by DT.

You should inspect the html using Chrome or Firefox developer tools and see if there is a jQuery error, if so that is the likely cause.

If you are still having issues please open an issue at the [knitrBootstrap bug tracker](https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap/issue).